Style Rules Azure DevOps 2024
I've been trying to create a set of rules in the Style section on the Azure DevOps task board. Unfortunately, the platform seems to allow the creation of only 10 rules. Does anyone know how to overcome this?
Thanks.

I looked everywhere on the internet, including Stack Overflow and Google, but I couldn't find a solution.

I am afraid that there is no such method can increase the style rules number in Azure DevOps.
This is not a user configured setting, it's a system limitation. Azure DevOps Service or On-Prem server only supports 10 style rules in Boards.
When you add 10 style rules, the + Add Styling rules option will grey out.
For example:

I can fully understand your requirement. Here are the suggestion tickets with the same requirements: Allow OR conditionals with styling rule criteria, or increase styling rule limit and Allow more card style rules in ADO settings.
You can add comments to the suggestion tickets to share your concerns and keep monitoring the update from the Azure DevOps Developer team.
